# dplyr: use chaining to pass variables

Tags: r, dplyr, chain, stringr

I'm new to `dplyr` and cannot figure out how to control the variables to pass through a chaining (`%>%`) command. Simple example: the `str_sub` function takes three arguments - the first is passed on through `%>%` but how can I get the last two? :

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(V1 = c("ABBEDHH", "DEFGH", "EFGF", "EEFD"), 
                 V2=c(4, 2, 1, 1), V3=c(5, 2, 2, 1), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

In base R I could do:

```
with(df, str_sub(V1, V2, V3))
```

and get:

```
## [1] "ED" "E"  "EF" "E"
```

How to chain this ? - I tried:

```
df %>% str_sub(V1, V2, V3) # Here V3 is unused arg since V1 is treated as 2nd arg

df %>% select(V1) %>% str_sub(V2, V3) # Here V2 and V3 are not recognized
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(lazyeval)

df %>% mutate(new = str_sub(V1, V2, V3))
#       V1 V2 V3 new
#1 ABBEDHH  4  5  ED
#2   DEFGH  2  2   E
#3    EFGF  1  2  EF
#4    EEFD  1  1   E
```

Note that `dplyr` is made for working with `data.frame`s, so input and output should be data.frames, not atomic vectors.

Comment: Perfect! For my need I would then add df %>% mutate(new = str_sub(V1, V2, V3)) %>% select(new)

Comment: @user3375672, yes, you can do that, but note that that works because the result is still a data.frame (with only 1 column), not an atomic vector.

Comment: @user3375672 you could use the slightly akward: `df %>% mutate(new = str_sub(V1, V2, V3)) %>% \`[[\`("new")`

Comment: @TylerRinker, good point. Although, iIf they really wanted a vector as output, my personal choice would simply be `with(df, str_sub(V1, V2, V3))`, as shown in the question.

Answer (score 1):

One could also do:

```
df %>% with(str_sub(V1, V2, V3))
```

as you want a vector anyway.  But now we're back in nested land.